# How to get the overall total count in matrix visual after using visual level filter

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a scenario where i have department with multiple codes. Each department has 3 sub departments with each sub departments having codes on different months. I am using matrix visual to show the count of Codes in each Department per month. I could get that in matrix. But when using the sub department in visual level filter, the total also gets filtered. I need to the get the overall / original total for each sub department even if the visual level filter is applied. 
Please help me to get the overall total in using measures as my source is live connection. 
Attached the image, PBIX , excel for reference in the below link

Thanks in Advance.

I have tried using All, AllSelected & Allexcept in measures.

https://filebin.net/uzhobbcdsec2zrh2

Comment: I think if you put your code or your works here (rather the link for downloads). People might be easier to help you.

Comment: The link i posted has the sample file to check my scenario with an image to show what i get and what i expect. Please try referring that. I couldnt show the full code here, but the measures i tried is as below Count overall = CALCULATE(COUNT('Parent'[Code]),ALL('Parent')),Count overall_allexcept = CALCULATE(COUNT('Parent'[Code]),ALLEXCEPT('Child',Child[Month])), Count overall = CALCULATE(COUNT('Parent'[Code]))

Comment: post some code that you've tried and a shot of your data model